# Is there any Gob MIME type?

Tags: go, mime, gob

Is there any (un)official Gob MIME Type, such as `application/x-gob`? The official documentation never mentions any MIME type.

I am not sure if I should use the same approach as Protobuf, which stopped using specific types in favour of the generic `application/octet-stream` (see [Protobuffer uses octet-stream as its default content type](https://github.com/google/protorpc/commit/eb03145a6a7c72ae6cc43867d9635a5b8d8c4545))

Comment: AFAIK, the gob format isn't formalised anywhere. So I would think that `application/octet-stream` would fit.

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is a catch-all and tells you *nothing* about the content. Your network connection must be between your own private nodes, I presume (gob makes little sense for a public endpoint). Should you consider transcoding into a recognised content type, e.g. to JSON?

Comment: @Rick-777 Yes that's one of the trade-offs. I opted for the custom type `application/x-gob` internally, and use `application/octet-stream` when knowing the content type is not necessary. Yes JSON could be used for public APIs, but protobuf is a "recognised" type and has a generic type.

Comment: Looks like protobuf might have erred. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html - this suggests `application/x-gob` is your best bet.